# FindControl not working with dynamically created controls

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an asp page that is using a master page. I create a few panels on the page with a AJAX call to a [Webmethod] on my code behind page. Here is the structure of the page itself...

```
<form runat="server" class="form-horizontal" id="frm_estRequest">
   <div id="mainContent" runat="server" >
    <div id="contentInner" runat="server>
           <asp:Panel  id="comp_list" runat="server"></asp:Panel>
        </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

I add the dynamically created controls to the "comp_list" panel via the webmethod. Here is the html that is being created in the webmethod...

```
Panel component = new Panel();
component.ID = "comp" + compNumber;
component.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<input type='hidden' value='" + 
compType + "' ID='compType_" + compNumber + "'/>"));
```

So what I am trying to do is get the value out of the Html Hiddenfield. Here is what I have to do that(which is not working for some reason).

```
ContentPlaceHolder cph =(ContentPlaceHolder)this.Master.FindControl("placeholder_content");
Control compList = (Control)cph.FindControl("frm_estRequest").FindControl("mainContent").FindControl("contentInner").FindControl("comp_list");
Control ct = (Control) compList.FindControl("comp" + i.ToString());
HiddenField compType = (HiddenField)ct.FindControl("compType_" + i.ToString());
```

I am able to get the "comp_list" control but that's is far is I can get. It keeps saying that ct is null. FYI, i is just a counter that is used to keep track of the controls that have been added to the page. My only idea is that maybe I should be using the clientID. Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

The controls are rendered as html and then returned via ajax to the page and then added to the div like so...

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
System.IO.StringWriter tw = new System.IO.StringWriter(sb);
HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(tw);
component.RenderControl(hw); 
return sb.ToString();

var req = $.ajax({ 
                    type: "POST", 
                    url: "EstRequest.aspx/createComponent", 
                    data: params,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
                    dataType: "json", 
                    success: function (data) { 
                            $('#<%= comp_list.ClientID%>').append(data.d) 
                            document.getElementById('<%= compNumber.ClientID %>').value = comp + 1;

                            $("#<%= compNumber.ClientID %>").live("click", function() {
                            $(this).next().slideToggle("fast")}); 

                            }, 
                    error: function (response) { debugger; alert("Error: " + params); }, 
                    failure: function (response) { 
                        alert(response.d); 
                    } 
                })
```

Comment: Are you trying to find the controls on postback? Did you re-add them as required before searching for them?

Comment: What event are you adding the dynamic controls?  It must be done before page_load, and as Oded said, they must be added back in the postback.

Comment: Your cast will not work re: the HiddenField. Why are you creating a LiteralControl then trying to find it as a HiddenField? While a HiddenField renders as a &lt;input type="hidden"&gt;, the cast itself won't work. Just add a new hiddenfield control then try to do a findcontrol on it.

Also, you can turn on "Trace" for the page level and see the control tree to find the rendered IDs, etc (its possible your literalcontrol 's ClientID rendering is not set to static)

Comment: The controls are being created with an on click event for a button. Also, I am trying to find the controls on a submit button click event. Thanks!

Comment: I have made the changes so that now I'm not trying to cast the literal to a hidden field, however the problem seems to be with getting the "component" panel.

Comment: You need to read @Oded's comment. You need to recreate the controls in your PAGE_LOAD method on postback. Otherwise, they won't exist for any processing you are doing.

Comment: @JeffSiver - Actually, `page_init` is the recommended location.

Comment: @Oded, you're correct; it's been a while since I worked with WebForms. Thanks.

Comment: Does anyone have a good example of recreating controls in the page_init event or suggestions on how to go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

> `Panel component = new Panel(); component.ID = "comp" + compNumber;
>   component.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl(""));
>
> //Add one line here
>
> comp_list.Add(component);`

try now it should work.

Comment: i am new here so i don't have much idea of formatting options available

Comment: I'm unable to do it this way since I am creating them in a webmethod.

Comment: i am not getting where you are adding controls to the "comp_list" panel. i dont see code for it. Moreover webmethods are static so i don't think you can add asp.net controls from it. You should try it using scripts.

Comment: $('#<%= comp_list.ClientID%>').append(data.d)
This line here is where I add the control in my javascript.